# Generating PDF server side using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I've looked on google for the ways to do this. I've found a lot of non maintained libraries. There doesn't seem to be any "fresh" information about this.

I need to generate my PDF on the server side. I'll have dynamic data.

Is the way to go still with PhantomJS?

Comment: my searching brought me similar answer. only PhantomJs. I make docker image with PhantomJs and used like pdf creator

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,you can use pdfkit library for pdf generation in node js.
i am also using the same library for pdf generation.
visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit .
or https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/blob/master/demo/browser.js
or
http://pdfkit.org/demo/browser.html

Comment: Documentation seems to be in coffee script? Is there any documentation in vanilla js?

Comment: How do you handle templating with it? I've seen that with phantom for example you can use handlebars to create templates.